# How can my website appear in search engines

Tags: seo, pagerank

I have developed a website for a firm that deals in pumps, valves and diesel engines. They require that when an interested user searches with some keywords like "Pump Dealers" or "Valve Dealers", their site should appear in the results. Currently I am not aware of how I can go about this, so my question is what should I do in order for better page ranking. I am using meaningful page titles and have enough text in every page.

Any suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly Pagerank is irrelevant these days, so don't worry about that.

You should ensure that you use Google's Webmaster Tools to check that Google knows about your site etc. This will tell you what things it is coming up for on Google.

Make sure that the page has the text on it you want to rank for - as you mention, titles, headers etc will help but don't over do it.

The main thing to do is to get links to your site – write interesting blog posts, contact customers etc so they link to you.

It really depends on who your competition is for those terms - if there are already 10 huge companies ranking for those terms then you are stuck.

The other way to do this is to buy Adwords – this will likely cost upwards of $5-10 a day to get any meaningful traffic though.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion , should I use meta tags for my cause , is it recommended.

Comment: Meta keywords aren't supported anymore, so ignore those. Meta description isn't used for ranking, but might be shown as the snippet on Google, so write that in a friendly and enticing way, but don't stuff it with keywords. The Title element is important, so think carefully about what is in there. To be honest though, links are so much more important than anything else.